# how to add anchor links in a Text web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365

We use Office 365 and have a private Sharepoint website setup for our company. I added a Text webpart to one of the pages on the site.

We want to add another links to some of the headers so we can link to them from other pages and have it jump down to those sections.

I'm not seeing an obvious way to add the anchor links.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do with the "modern" Text Web Part as you cannot edit the HTML. You would need to add a NAME or ID attribute to an HTML tag.

A recent discussion as to why here: [How to use html code in modern UI](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/246032/how-to-use-html-code-in-modern-ui)

A project to let you add HTML/JavaScript to modern pages (but it's a complex solution): https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

Or create a custom SPFx WebPart.